# Dark mode plots in Jupyter Notebook - Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and I'm currently using the dark solarized theme on it from JupyterThemes.

I notice that my plots are not in dark mode and the text is still black and unreadable on the solarized background. The readme for JupyterThemes suggests creating a startup.ipy in ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/startup.ipy and writing

```
# import jtplot submodule from jupyterthemes
from jupyterthemes import jtplot

# currently installed theme will be used to
# set plot style if no arguments provided
jtplot.style()
```

I have created this file but nothing has changed. I've also tried following this guide (https://medium.com/@rbmsingh/making-jupyter-dark-mode-great-5adaedd814db) but again my plots haven't changed.

Any help? I enjoy using dark mode in Jupyter Notebook and I would like to have legible plots.

Answer (score 18):

When I work in dark mode I add the style line below after the matplotlib import and all the graphs in the notebook are formated with a black background and white text.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
plt.style.use('dark_background')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you change .pytplot to pyplot please?

Answer (score 6):

I found one solution for expanding the plot canvas a bit so that x and y ticks will get visible.

You need to add one line `plt.style.use('default')` after importing the matplot lib module in notebook.

[image]

See my ticks are outside the canvas before.

[image]

After adding the line the tick got added to the canvas itself no further modification was needed.

[image]

As you can see in the above image this will pull the x and y ticks in the canvas to make it visible without changing or modifying ticks or plot color, it will make it easier to collaborate your work with others.

Comment: indeed just ```plt.style.use('default')``` solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem, I resolved changing the character (’) by (') in (https://medium.com/@rbmsingh/making-jupyter-dark-mode-great-5adaedd814db), and now it's working, below it's the text corrected, good luck !

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from jupyterthemes import jtplot

jtplot.style(theme='monokai', context='notebook', ticks=True, grid=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Jupyter Notebook is installed using Anaconda . You need to install Jupyterthemes in you conda environment:

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyterthemes`